# Array merge and remove duplicate issue PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays, populated from result.

1) users_facebook & 2) users_twitter

```
Array
(
    [users_facebook] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => "180",
                [email] => "",
                [first_name] => "Djon",
                [last_name] => "Katview"
        ),
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => "182",
                [email] => "",
                [first_name] => "Awaaru",
                [last_name] => "Bhejafry"
        )
    ),

    [users_twitter] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => "180",
                [email] => "",
                [first_name] => "Djon",
                [last_name] => "Katview"
        ),
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => "181",
                [email] => "",
                [first_name] => "Kavritis",
                [last_name] => "Abrfafda"
        ),
        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => "182",
                [email] => "",
                [first_name] => "Awaaru",
                [last_name] => "Bhejafry"
        )
    ),
)
```

I want to select elements having same **"id"** in both arrays and append it to new array, say like "users_final_array"

And when it's appended to new array, I want to remove it from both the arrays.

**p.s.**: the unmatched elements must remain as it is.. I am messing with it since almost 3 hrs

Added:

result array will be like:

```
Array
(
    [users_facebook] => Array
    (
    ),

    [users_twitter] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => "181",
                [email] => "",
                [first_name] => "Kavritis",
                [last_name] => "Abrfafda"
            )
    ),

    [users_final_array] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => "180",
                [email] => "",
                [first_name] => "Djon",
                [last_name] => "Katview"
        ),
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => "182",
                [email] => "",
                [first_name] => "Awaaru",
                [last_name] => "Bhejafry"
        )
    ),
)
```

Comment: tried foreach loop and all messed up, also tried array_intersect but it was a wrong way indeed..

Answer (score 2):

Convert this to json to array by decoding. Then Try by merging these two array into one array. After merger use array_unique() function to remove duplicate as follows

```
array_unique($merge_array);
```

Comment: you will get some notices of array to string conversion. can remove the items from the 2 array by using `array_key_exists` and a foreachloop

Answer (score 0):

First of all these two arrays is JSON arrays, so decode theme to a php's one:

```
$array = json_decode($response, true);
```

and thene, just use the php "array_merge" and select both of them (facebook and twitter)

Comment: I don't want to merge, I want similar elements from both array into another array.. Merging of array will process with all the elements and not only the similar ones

Answer (score 0):

[array_intersect](http://php.net/array_intersect)

```
<?php

$res = '{
    "users_facebook": [
        {
            "id": "180",
            "email": "",
            "first_name": "Djon",
            "last_name": "Matfew"
        },
        {
            "id": "182",
            "email": "",
            "first_name": "Awaaru",
            "last_name": "Bhejafry"
        }
    ],
    "users_twitter": [
        {
            "id": "180",
            "email": "",
            "first_name": "Djon",
            "last_name": "Matfew"
        },
        {
            "id": "181",
            "email": "",
            "first_name": "Kavritis",
            "last_name": "Abrfafda"
        },
        {
            "id": "182",
            "email": "",
            "first_name": "Awaaru",
            "last_name": "Bhejafry"
        }
    ]
}';

$res = json_decode($res, true);

print_r(array_intersect($res['users_facebook'],$res['users_twitter']));

?>
```

than [array_diff](http://php.net/array_diff) to see what's left from original response

Comment: it didn't worked, I have used array_intersect and it does display both equal elements perfectly but when I use array_diff it doesn't show me any element. and I also need to delete those similar elements from both array as well